# How to capture drawn shape on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have taken example of code from this page

https://github.com/googlemaps/js-samples/blob/gh-pages/drawing/drawing-tools.html

is there any way to add "id" / selector to  drawn shape.

any help is appreciated.

```
  var drawingManager;
  var selectedShape;
  var colors = ['#1E90FF', '#FF1493', '#32CD32', '#FF8C00', '#4B0082'];
  var selectedColor;
  var colorButtons = {};

  function clearSelection() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setEditable(false);
      selectedShape = null;
    }
  }

  function setSelection(shape) {
    clearSelection();
    selectedShape = shape;
    shape.setEditable(true);
    selectColor(shape.get('fillColor') || shape.get('strokeColor'));
  }

  function deleteSelectedShape() {
    if (selectedShape) {
      selectedShape.setMap(null);
    }
  }

  function selectColor(color) {
    selectedColor = color;
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
      var currColor = colors[i];
      colorButtons[currColor].style.border = currColor == color ? '2px solid #789' : '2px solid #fff';
    }

    // Retrieves the current options from the drawing manager and replaces the
    // stroke or fill color as appropriate.
    var polylineOptions = drawingManager.get('polylineOptions');
    polylineOptions.strokeColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('polylineOptions', polylineOptions);

    var rectangleOptions = drawingManager.get('rectangleOptions');
    rectangleOptions.fillColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('rectangleOptions', rectangleOptions);

    var circleOptions = drawingManager.get('circleOptions');
    circleOptions.fillColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('circleOptions', circleOptions);

    var polygonOptions = drawingManager.get('polygonOptions');
    polygonOptions.fillColor = color;
    drawingManager.set('polygonOptions', polygonOptions);
  }

  function setSelectedShapeColor(color) {
    if (selectedShape) {
      if (selectedShape.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
        selectedShape.set('strokeColor', color);
      } else {
        selectedShape.set('fillColor', color);
      }

      selectedShape.setAttribute("id", "test-capture");
    }
  }

  function makeColorButton(color) {
    var button = document.createElement('span');
    button.className = 'color-button';
    button.style.backgroundColor = color;
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
      selectColor(color);
      setSelectedShapeColor(color);
    });

    return button;
  }

   function buildColorPalette() {
     var colorPalette = document.getElementById('color-palette');
     for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; ++i) {
       var currColor = colors[i];
       var colorButton = makeColorButton(currColor);
       colorPalette.appendChild(colorButton);
       colorButtons[currColor] = colorButton;
     }
     selectColor(colors[0]);
   }

  function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 20,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(17.3850, 78.4867),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    });

    var polyOptions = {
      strokeWeight: 0,
      fillOpacity: 0.45,
      editable: true
    };
    // Creates a drawing manager attached to the map that allows the user to draw
    // markers, lines, and shapes.
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
      markerOptions: {
        draggable: true
      },
      polylineOptions: {
        editable: true
      },
      rectangleOptions: polyOptions,
      circleOptions: polyOptions,
      polygonOptions: polyOptions,
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        if (e.type != google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
        // Switch back to non-drawing mode after drawing a shape.
        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);

        // Add an event listener that selects the newly-drawn shape when the user
        // mouses down on it.
        var newShape = e.overlay;
        newShape.type = e.type;
        google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'click', function() {
          setSelection(newShape);
        });
        setSelection(newShape);
      }
    });

    // Clear the current selection when the drawing mode is changed, or when the
    // map is clicked.
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'drawingmode_changed', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', clearSelection);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('delete-button'), 'click', deleteSelectedShape);

    buildColorPalette();
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  function takeScreenCapture(){
         var element = $("#map");

        html2canvas(element, {
            useCORS: true,
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var dataUrl= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                document.write('<img src="' + dataUrl + '"/>');
            }
        });

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do two things here.

1) In the overlaycomplete event handler you get a reference to the drawn shape, you can save it into an array. Then you can use the array index as an id for your drawn features.

2) You could use GeoJSON. GeoJSON objects in the data layer can be given an id and you can use this id to do things to the object. See the the [getFeatureById() method in the data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data). For more information on how to edit objects in the datalayer read this blog post:

https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/2015/04/interactive-data-layers-in-javascript.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will give a try and let you know.